# Why is the term $(2n+1)$ in the solution angles of sine and also in its taylor sum? Is this coincidence?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Given $ \sin (x) = a $ the solutions are given by  (with $ A = \arcsin a $)
$$ x = A + 2 \pi n$$
$$ x = (\pi - A) + 2 \pi n = - A + (\pi + 2 \pi n) = - A + (2n + 1) \pi $$

The taylor sum is given by:

$$ \sin x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1} $$

How can you quickly see the connection of this factor? Could be trivial, but I don't see it that fast.

And the $ 2n + 1 $ basically represents the following property of sine:

[image: unit circle]

Does this also hold for cosine and the hyperbolic trigonemetric formulas? And even exponential sum (since it is related by the Moivre's Formula?)

Comment: Maybe also 

$\sin(\frac{x}{\pi}) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!\pi^{2n+1}} x^{2n+1}$  

so that you have alternating factors in the denominator $(2n+1)\pi$, $2n\pi$, ...

Comment: What do you mean by "the connection of this factor"? It is not clear at all to me what you asking about. And what "property" of sine is the diagram supposed to indicate? That in a right triangle it is the ratio of opposite side to hypotenuse, maybe? Why do you feel this has anything to do with "$2n+1$" in the Taylor series?